# Dealing with account security when user logged in through facebook or google

Tags: php, facebook, security

So I think I reached a security issue and I'm not sure how to handle it.

I'm enabling my users to change their registered email and password on my website. For these two actions, they should type in their current password (and also confirm the email with a token). It's all good, but when the user has done social login, he would not have a password to type.

My first idea was to just skip the typing password field when the user has no registered pass, but thinking again, it might be a security issue (he leaves it logged in somewhere and someone else could easily hijack the account)

So, what would be a good way of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect against email address changes when the user doesn't have a password to type, you could send the user an email that they have to click in order to authorise their email address change.

This would only work if they haven't left their email account logged into too.

The flow would be:

1. Navigate to change email page.
2. Click button to authorise email address change - this sends an email to the user's existing email account, containing a 64 bit token, randomly generated by a cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator.
3. The user opens their email account and click the link.
4. If the token is valid, the page followed from the link allows their email address to be altered.
5. If the token is not used within say 6 hours, the token is expired.

Store the tokens hashed by SHA-256 in your database, to prevent any data leaks from allowing an attacker to change the email addresses of other users by constructing email reset links using the raw values.

Answer (score 0):

We use google, paypal and facebook logins as authorization at our online shops. We handled it, that the user can only change their email address *(=account username)* when they registered directly at our shop software (with email verification) and only after the **correct password** has been entered.

When the user has registered by an open auth service (like facebook) he can only alter his email adress *(=account username)*, if he **transforms his open auth account to a real account**. To do so he must first login by open auth, than he has to enter a valid email adress and a **security token send to the old email address** (provided by the open auth service) to verifiy he is the legit owner of the address. After that he has to choose a regular password to login.

Answer (score -1):

Hold a flag somewhere (for example, a database column) to determine whether the user registered via a "social login". If it is set, the user can change its password. If it isn't, he doesn't come in with a password in the first place.

Comment: The OP was asking how to deal with the security issue that they raised, not how to track whether the user has an existing password.